# Какой же все-таки знак?

Tags: пунктуация

**Если что () позвоню.**

Answer (score 3):

Почему же... В правилах и о тире говорится. Например, у Розенталя:

§111. Тире в сложноподчиненном предложении

При интонационном подчеркивании придаточные изъяснительные, реже **условные** и уступительные, **стоящие впереди главного предложения**, **могут отделяться от него не запятой, а тире...**

Comment: Да, я слышал о таком, но, по-моему, тире можно влепить везде, где хочешь что-то подчеркнуть интонацией, такой универсальный знак.

Comment: Ну не совсем "везде"... Но тут прежде всего идет речь о том, что запятая *заменяется* на тире. Так что помимо общих разговоров об универсальности знака, надо ещё и конкретно разобрать причины и условия для такой замены.

Answer (score 2):

На мой взгляд, нет достаточных оснований отрицать ни тире, ни запятую в данном случае. Оба знака приемлемы, ведь "оправдания" (объяснения) для каждого из них вполне логичны. Если автор высказывания желает подчеркнуть паузу после *если что* (интонация будет восходящей) - поставит тире. Оно вроде бы более уместно, так как действительно это самое *если что* является неполным предложением, плюс придаточное - перед главным (и правило, приведенное [@Ларf](/users/498/%D0%BB%D0%B0%D1%80f), гласит, что придаточные **могут** отделяться тире, а не запятой, но ведь это не обязательно). Поэтому запятую, думаю, отвергать не стоит. Если произнести без паузы и без повышения интонации эту фразу, достаточно будет и запятой.

Answer (score 1):

Я бы поставил тире. Но это мой индивидуальный каприз, основанный на чисто интуитивном чувстве языка. Логика следующая. Полная фраза, которая имеется в виду, выглядит так: "Если что-то случится, то я тебе позвоню". Тире как бы заменяет собой все опущенные за ненадобностью слова.

Comment: Здесь, уважаемый, работает не каприз и интуиция, а конкретное правило, которое упомянуто коллегой Ларf

Answer (score 0):

Запятая. *"Если что"* - придаточная часть, которую надо отделить от главной. 
Конечно, можно сказать, будто в придаточной опущено сказуемое (случится, произойдет), поэтому неплохо было бы поставить тире, но негде, так как в правилах русского языка сказано, что придаточная отделяется от главной запятой.

Answer (score 0):

Я бы не задумываясь поставила запятую: ***Если что, позвоню.*** Предложение *ЕСЛИ ЧТО*  в устной речи и в современной художественной литературе встречается очень часто. Придаточное "если что не так" или "если что случится" в силу частого употребления сократилось до двух слов - союза и местоимения что. Запятая ставится традиционно, чаще, чем тире.
*Куда можно спрятаться, если что. Я забрался поглубже и достал сигарету. (Андрей Геласимов. Фокс Малдер похож на свинью)  "Товарищ начмед, все бегут, а нам куда?" ― взмолился в смятении простодушный прапорщик, будучи готов, если что, побежать. (Олег Павлов. Карагандинские девятины, или Повесть последних дней)*

Comment: Уважаемая коллега! То, что Вы пишете, относится к случаям, когда в начале предложения идет главная часть, а при препозиции придаточного условного, изъяснительного ставится тире, а не запятая.

Answer (score 0):

А по-моему, это предложение равнозначно по смыслу сложносочинённому предложению "Что-то случится — и я позвоню", где тире обозначает быструю смену событий или неожиданный результат. Либо к бессоюзному со значением причины. Поэтому выбираю тире.